# check and display label from database

Tags: c#, ms-access

Sorry for my bad english.

Here's my question. I can type different usernames into `tb_acc` and display existing users full name in `Label1`, but for users that don't exist, it doesn't display the string `User not found.` Is `DBNull.Value` not applicable here? I have `AutoPostBack` on the textbox set to `true`.

```
if (IsPostBack)
{
            try
            {

                using (OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand("select childName from family where childID='" + tb_acc.Text + "'", con))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    OleDbDataReader myReader2 = null;
                    myReader2 = com.ExecuteReader();

                    while (myReader2.Read())
                    {

                        if (myReader2["childName"] != DBNull.Value)
                        {
                            Label1.Text = (myReader2["childName"].ToString()); //user full Name
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Label1.Text = "User not found.";
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write("Error: " + ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }


        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are expecting that user exist. Change while to If:

```
if (myReader2.Read())
{
    if (myReader2["childName"] != DBNull.Value)
    {
        Label1.Text = (myReader2["childName"].ToString()); //user full Name
    }
    else
    {
        Label1.Text = "User with no name";
    }
}
else
{
    Label1.Text = "User not found.";
}
```

Comment: thank you sir! really silly mistake, sorry I'm new to c# !